# Android google maps move map at runtime

Tags: android, google-maps

When I start my google maps activity v2 - the map appeared - how can I achieve that the map
can now move a bit (maybe circle around a Location) - like as I do it with my fingers ?

help, tuts, hints would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by reading [the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views#moving_the_camera).

There are functions like `GoogleMap.animateCamera` that do the job.